# Unit testing WinForms forms

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, reflection, expression-trees

In unit testing .net winforms, we're coming across the need to manipulate and verify the state of various form controls, as well as to fire events on those controls. The problem is that the controls are private by default on the form, and the test method can't get at them.

So far, we've resorted to using magic strings to get the controls via reflection. This works, but it's brittle. Tests will break if the control name changes.

Changing all the controls to internal works, but it's a bit of a pain in that we have to remember to do it for each and every control we might want to access in a test.

I thought maybe I might use expression trees to get around the "privateness" of the control, but nothing obvious comes to mind as to how to go about building such code.

There's also the problem of raising events. So far, we're magic strings to hold event names, then using reflection to locate the *OnXXX* method and invoking it, but again, we'd like to do away with that.

Is there a way to use expression trees (or any other semantics or mechanisms) to access private controls, in order to manipulate or verify their state and fire their events?

Comment: Mocking frameworks are made to simulate such events and dependencies so you don't have to do full setup. Look into Moq. Also, you don't unit test private functions. You unit test the public functions that call into them and test for side effects.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I'm well aware of all of that, and we're using Moq to full effect when testing services and utils, but that doesn't help us with testing the behavior of various complex forms we have. We're looking to JustMock to help with mocking away some more dependencies, but ultimately, we want to exercise and observe a form's behavior, and for that, we need to access the controls. (Unless you're advocating we mock the controls themselves, but that seems like an inordinate amount of very error-prone work...)